# Scraping Issue. Why no data is being scraped?

Tags: python, html, css, web-scraping

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://www.colonialzone-dr.com/c-dominicanismos-dictionary'
page = requests.get(URL)

print("testing")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

words = soup.find_all('p', class_="entry-content")
print(len(words))

for word in words:
    print(word.text)
```

// Nothing is being displayed on my console and the length variable returns 0 which means nothing is being scraped.

Comment: There are no `p` tag elements on that page with `entry-content` class.

Comment: All the words are in a p tag element inside the div class="entry-content" || Or am I over looking something?

Comment: You can only give tags which has its corresponding class/id attributes. Here in this case `div` with tag `entry-content`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you see html there is div in which all p tags are present so you can take that div tag with associate class and then take p tag from it so you will get your output

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://www.colonialzone-dr.com/c-dominicanismos-dictionary'
page = requests.get(URL)

print("testing")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

main_div = soup.find('div', attrs={"class":"entry-content"})
words=main_div.find_all("p")
                                   

for word in words:
    print(word.text)
```

Output:

```
testing
The slang used in Dominican Republic.
C – ce
*Caballo – person similar to a tigre but a little more decent
*Cabron – a large male goat,also means displeased
*Cacaito – candy
 ....
```

Answer (score 0):

There were no `p` tags with entry-content? Remove that and it should work

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://www.colonialzone-dr.com/c-dominicanismos-dictionary'
page = requests.get(URL)

print("testing")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

words = soup.find_all('p')
print(len(words))

for word in words:
    print(word.text)
```

But if you want content of p inside the div with class "entry-content" then

```
entryContent=soup.find('div',attrs={"class":"entry-content"})
words=entryContent.find_all("p")
```

Answer (score 0):

you are passing additional parameter to words as entry-content, but there is no need to pass additional parameter.

```
words = soup.find_all('p', class_="entry-content")
```

try instead of that,

```
words = soup.find_all('p')
```

then it will get all the content with p and it gives you the length.

```
print(len(words))
```

i hope it will help to you..